# STM32L431KC Clock well configured but there is a delay when it's running

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

- I have made a board based on `STM32L431KC` MCU and when I try to flash the blinking LED  it works but with latency, and when I change the delay to 1s (1000 ms)  the led doesn't blink anymore.
- The clock configuration is in the `systemclock_config` function and it uses the internal `16Mhz` clock (HSI).
- Also I've tested this code with `Nucleo Stm32L432K board` (because both have the same clock tree) and it works without any latency.
- I've added the schematics of the MCU
- The boot0 pin  is LOW

This is the main.c file:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_2);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(char *file, uint32_t line)
{}
#endif
```

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] please, why all the comments?!

Comment: I've removed all of the comments,Thanks Antti!

Comment: Check if your empty error handler is called by puting some endless loop in there. You shold able to halt the system within this loop with the debugger. What is your desired target speed? If the PLL is not locked during clock setup within a defined time, the controller will run with slower speed, propably with the default internal 16MHz.

Comment: What do you mean by "latency"?  Latency is the time between a physical event and the processing of that event in software.  It is not at all clear how that term applies in this case.  Tell us what you expect to happen, what actually happens and how you measured it happening.

Comment: @veeman ; It seems 16MHz is the intended speed. there is no attempt to start the PLL: `RCC_PLL_NONE` is used.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, what I mean with latency is  "delay" @Clifford
The system is running with a speed different than  the speed that I've configured

Comment: The problem is that I have the STM32L432KC nucleo board and when I flash it with the same code  it works perfectly. L432KC and L431KC  have the same clock tree.

Comment: @Ahmed.R : Running at a different speed is neither delay not latency.  Clarifications should be edited into the question not placed in response comments.  When you say "speed" do you mean the flashing frequency is not correct, and if so, what is the frequency or period?  Note that `HAL_delay` assumes that the SysTick timebase is 1ms.

Comment: @Clifford I use Keil for compiling and flashing  and every time I change the frequency of the MCU ,I change it  in keil and debugging , but the every time the system is not running as expected , I know that the Hal_delay is based on the 1ms of Systick timebase  ,but what I can see that my configuration is right ,but I get different resullt, is there any problem with the code ?